# Using text input value as a float

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I'm trying to use the text value from a text field as a float (to update a slider), but it's apparently not as straight-forward as I thought.

```
self.speedSlider.value = self.numberOfSecs.text
```

That errors because an NSString is expected. I also can't cast the text into a float, it seems.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Casting doesn't actually change the type of what's casted; think of it as a compile-time declaration of "no really, I know what I'm doing, this X is in fact of type Y"

Comment: Slider value property is only accepted float value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract value using floatValue method (if your string represents a valid number):

```
self.speedSlider.value = [self.numberOfSecs.text floatValue];
```

Comment: Thanks — that did it. I was trying to cast via (float)numberofSecs.text. Didn't realize I could do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
self.speedSlider.value = [self.numberOfSecs.text floatValue];
```

You must Convert String to Float...!